# How to fix the problem of separating three side-by-side elements in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have three elements that are side-by-side on the personal website I am creating. I am wanting to structure them like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQEf3.jpg

But instead, the middle element doesn't seem to create freely to editing the margins. Example, "margin-left" doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

THis is what my website currently looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuHs6.jpg

I am beginning to think that I should have a much deeper grasp about HTML and its semantics, versus trying to learn experimentally and through playing around with the different <..>. Has anyone got any recommendations for this? I should like to say that I have learnt coding HTML and CSS and now JavaScript, purely through free resources, purely through freecodecamp.org

I've tried floating the outside comments, left and right respectively and the middle "center" but then the center element is acting oddly, again, by being relatively higher (has a margin-top value greater than the other two).

Here is the section pertaining to the three elements:

```
<div class="Services1">
    <h2> Fine Art and Calligraphy</h2>
    <a href="sites/blog.html">
        <img src="images/FineArts.png" id="Fine">
    </a>           
</div>  

<div class="Service2">
    <h2> Chess and Mathematics Tutoring</h2>
    <a href="sites/services.html">
        <img src="images/Math.png" style="width: 300px">
    </a>
</div> 

<div class="Services3">
    <h2> Web Dev and Design </h2>
    <a href="sites/services.html">
        <img src="images/Web-Developer-Skills-1.jpg" style="width: 400px;">
    </a>
</div>
```

whereas the CSS that pertains to these is:

```
.Services1 {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    text-align: center
}

.Services2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}

.Services3 {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -330px;
    margin-right: 90px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Please be aware, I have tried `float: center;` to the middle element without avail. Margin's don't seem to be working either. Also it seems stuck to the left element. Very strange.

Comment: There is no such thing as `float: center` and I agree with what you said. You don't know enough about HTML and CSS. Your question is also too broad and opinion based as shown by all the opinions and commentary offered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way using flex-box would be to wrap your divs in a container div with class of e.g. `flex-container`:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="Services1">
    <h2> Fine Art and Calligraphy</h2>
    <a href="sites/blog.html">
        <img src="images/FineArts.png" id="Fine">
    </a>           
  </div>  

  <div class="Service2">
    <h2> Chess and Mathematics Tutoring</h2>
    <a href="sites/services.html">
        <img src="images/Math.png" style="width: 300px">
    </a>
  </div> 

  <div class="Services3">
    <h2> Web Dev and Design </h2>
    <a href="sites/services.html">
        <img src="images/Web-Developer-Skills-1.jpg" style="width: 400px;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and add the following CSS to `flex-container`:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

you may need to remove some of the margins and floats you have in your original CSS.

I would recommend looking into some basic flexbox concepts, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Make a container `<div>` around all 3 elements

```
display: flex; 
justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: This would be the best solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

The [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) format might serve you better. You would need a parent element around your three columns but `display: flex` would give you a lot more control than using `float`.

[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has a **very** good reference guide to using flexbox.

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

[ class^="Service"] {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">

  <div class="Services1">
    <h2> Fine Art and Calligraphy</h2>
    <a href="sites/blog.html"><img src="//placekitten.com/303/303" id="Fine"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="Service2">
    <h2> Chess and Mathematics Tutoring</h2>
    <a href="sites/services.html"><img src="//placekitten.com/303/303" id="Fine"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="Services3">
    <h2> Web Dev and Design </h2>
    <a href="sites/services.html"><img src="//placekitten.com/303/303" id="Fine"></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to flexbox is the less well-known CSS grid (not to be confused with table). This might come in handy though especially if you plan on expanding your content.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using CSS Flexbox if you are familiar with it.
I also noticed that the img in the services2 element is causing the strange offset.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Carlos said about making a container div around all 3 elements, `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` -- in this case you should get rid of those floats for sure. If you want to keep the floats in those classes, all three need to have the same float (either `float: left` or `float: right`), and then you should tamper with the margins to get the spacing you want.

Also, avoid styling width and height in the HTML, and you are better off making a div with a `background-image: url("../images/FineArts.png")`(in the CSS). This way you have a lot more control of the image and its size. I hope this helps.